# How to override the wx.grid.GridTableBase.SetRowLabelValue() method to set the values of a virtual grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm making a python application with wx.Python that has a table with lots of data. To make the grid usable I am trying to define a virtual table. To use the wx.grid.GridTableBase.SetRowLabelValue() method to define my column headings the documentation says the default version does nothing, you must override this method in your derived class. I just don't know what to do with the column label in the SetColLabelValue() method. Where do I store the label that I pass to it? Thanks.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

gridcontents=[["x","x","x","x"],["y","y","y","y"],["z","z","z","z"],["l","l","l","l"]]

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel=wx.Panel(self)
        self.sizer=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.grid=wx.grid.Grid(self.panel, -1)
        self.CreateGrid()
        self.sizer.Add(self.grid,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

    def CreateGrid(self):
        table = HugeTable()
        self.grid.SetTable(table,True)

class HugeTable(wx.grid.GridTableBase):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.grid.GridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.SetColLabelValue(0,"Row 1")

    def SetRowLabelValue(self, row, label):
        return(label)

    def SetColLabelValue(self, col, label):
        #not sure what to put here
        print(label)
        return(label)

    def GetNumberRows(self):
        return len(gridcontents)

    def GetNumberCols(self):
        return len(gridcontents[0])

    def IsEmptyCell(self, row, col):
        return False

    def GetValue(self, row, col):
        return str( gridcontents[row][col] )

app = wx.App()
frm = Frame(None)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Why dont you directly subclass from wxGrid?

Comment: @macroland Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. I'm fairly new to python and programming. Can you please explain more?

Comment: @macroland , I think I understand what you mean. I don't directly subclass from wxGrid because the documentation for SetRowLabelValue says "The default version does nothing, i.e. the label is not stored. You must override this method in your derived class if you wish wx.grid.Grid.SetRowLabelValue to work."

Comment: And looking at the code for wx.grid it looks like the only function in the SetColLabelValue() method is "pass"

Comment: I am not sure about the Python version but in C++ you dont need to do anything unless you want to customize the look. I assume Python and C++ follow the same logic as Python is just a wrap around the C++ code, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The following information is provided in Rappin & Dunn's book "wxPython in Action".

The entire explanation is given on page 435 in the section that describes how to manage the row and column headers of the grid.

In a nutshell, for a grid control using an external grid table, the column headers are set by overriding the GetColLabel Value. Since the returned value is determined dynamically by the code you put in the overridden method, there's no need to override or call the setter method.

So, do 3 things to the code.

1. No need for the setter method SetColLabelValue.
2. Add a variable for the column labels.
   e.g. col_labels = ['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4']
3. Add the GetColLabelValue getter method.
   def GetColLabelValue(self, col):
   return col_labels[col]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).